# PureBasic - how can i simulate pressing F1 or F2 keyboard button?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, keyboard-shortcuts, purebasic

From Linux i am trying to make a small executable file for Windows 7/8 and Mac.
with [PureBasic language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PureBasic.).
How can i press F1 or F2 keyboard button using PureBasic? 
I tried following but getting a linker error.

[image]

```
If OpenWindow(0, #PB_Ignore, #PB_Ignore, 200, 200, "Shortcut test", #PB_Window_SystemMenu | #PB_Window_ScreenCentered)

   AddKeyboardShortcut(0, #PB_Shortcut_Apps,101);      (=) - somewhere near the Space key
   AddKeyboardShortcut(0, #PB_Shortcut_Clear,102)
   AddKeyboardShortcut(0, #PB_Shortcut_Command,103)
   AddKeyboardShortcut(0, #PB_Shortcut_Execute,104)
   AddKeyboardShortcut(0, #PB_Shortcut_Help,105)
   AddKeyboardShortcut(0, #PB_Shortcut_Menu,106)
   ;AddKeyboardShortcut(0, #PB_Shortcut_Next,107)
   AddKeyboardShortcut(0, #PB_Shortcut_Pause,108);      Pause - should be beside F12 or so
   AddKeyboardShortcut(0, #PB_Shortcut_Print,109)
   ;AddKeyboardShortcut(0, #PB_Shortcut_Prior,110)
   AddKeyboardShortcut(0, #PB_Shortcut_Scroll,111);      ScrollLock
   AddKeyboardShortcut(0, #PB_Shortcut_Select,112)
   AddKeyboardShortcut(0, #PB_Shortcut_Separator,113)
   AddKeyboardShortcut(0, #PB_Shortcut_Snapshot,114)

   Repeat
      Select WaitWindowEvent()
      Case #PB_Event_Menu
         z=EventMenu()
         If z>99 And z<115
            Debug "Found key for the event #"+Str(z)
         EndIf
      Case #PB_Event_CloseWindow
         Break
      EndSelect
   ForEver

EndIf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Windows you can post following messages:

```
    PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_F1, 0);
    PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYUP, VK_F1, 0);
```

So you should find in your language, a way to PostMessage to your window. There are other Win API functions like: keybd_event, SendInput look here for more info:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2334/Toggling-the-Num-Lock-Caps-Lock-an-Scroll-Lock-ke

I know nothing about PureBasic but after quick googling I was able to find forum where something similar is being done:

http://www.purebasic.fr/english/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=47321